# AWS lambda function to delete contents of s3 bucket using python

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

How do I write lambda function in AWS(python) to delete the contents of S3 buckets. please share the template on this regard I just want the codes.

Comment: *"I just want the codes"* is not how SO works. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/empty-bucket.html https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/delete-bucket.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will help you in setting up a Python based lambda - including entry point for handler:
https://stackify.com/aws-lambda-with-python-a-complete-getting-started-guide/

Once that is figured out, you need to create an s3 client using:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client("s3")
```

Then you can follow the user guide to empty bucket:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/empty-bucket.html

Also note that the lambda is run using an assumed role, please make sure the IAM role has relevant permissions:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html

Comment: Note that there is no such thing as an "empty bucket API".